# Disable warning message in scribus

Tags: python, svg, warnings

When importing a svg file to the DTP programme "Scribus" it shows a warning message (with just one OK-button), that has to be confirmed to go on. This stops my Python Script from working.

So I need a possibility to either confirm the message or - even better - to stop Scribus from showing this message. (something like the "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" in Excel VBA)

A possible solution would be to send an "Enter" command using sendkeys, but I don't like that because the command could miss the target.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinauto/0.5.1

and here:
http://pywinauto.github.io/

It might not be a ready solution to your challenge within Scribus, but it might point you in the right direction. Or the developers could help you.

Check the Scribus website too, there is a very helpful mailing list running, which has helped me several times.

---

And could some veteran please create a "Scribus" tag here?

Answer (score 1):

contributors are working on refactoring those parts of code where scribus blocks the scripts with popups.

patches have already been applied to the 1.5svn development version to better manage them.

my hint to you:

- use the stable version for creating your documents
- but -- as long as the new stable 1.6 is not out -- use scribus 1.5 for running your scripts unattended, using the documents you created with 1.4
- and if you then hit further stoppers report them to the scribus issues tracker (or make a patch and submit it there!)